# Confusion about $\omega^{CK}_{\omega_1+1}$

Tags: computability, ordinals

This is a shorter and more to the point version of the question I deleted few hours ago (which was much more complicated than necessary). My feeling is that I might have some basic confusion here, so the question might have a very easy answer (but I will go ahead and ask). Nevertheless, I have been thinking about it since yesterday and having trouble identifying where I am going wrong.

Let's denote $\theta=\omega^{CK}_{\omega_1+1}$. Now $\theta \geq \omega_1 \cdot 2$ should be true. Now consider an (infinite) computational model $Comp$ (just like ORM) but with an added instruction of the form $v:=\omega_1$. Let $S$ be set of all ordinals $X$ (with $\omega_1 \leq X < \omega_1 \cdot 2$) for which there is a program (of $Comp$) that starts from zero input and halts with a certain designated variable exactly equal to $X$. Now clearly, $S$ can't contain all elements between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_1 \cdot 2$, since there are only countably many $Comp$ programs.

Now let's fix a value $\alpha$ such that $\omega_1 \leq \alpha < \omega_1 \cdot 2$ and $\alpha \notin S$. Considering definition-8 in this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007209000098): "An ordinal $\alpha \geq \omega$ is admissible iff there is no total $\Sigma_1(L_{\alpha})$-definable function f that maps an ordinal  $\beta<\alpha$ cofinally into $\alpha$." As far as I can guess isn't "*total $\Sigma_1(L_{\alpha})$-definable function*" supposed to mean $\alpha$-recursive function? *[please correct if this is wrong]*

The thing that is bothering me here is that if we set $\lambda_0=\alpha$ doesn't the previous definition implies a chain of values $\lambda_n<\lambda_{n-1}<....<\lambda_1<\lambda_0$ such that for each $i$ there is a $\lambda_{i-1}$-recursive function (with cofinality $\lambda_{i-1}$) from $\lambda_i$ to $\lambda_{i-1}$. Furthermore, let's denote $\lambda_n$ as the first point in the chain where $\lambda_n \in S$ (for $0 \leq i < n$ we have $\lambda_i \notin S$). I think the chain will not abruptly drop below $\omega_1$ so the assumption that $\lambda_n \in S$ seems justified. *[please correct if this is wrong]*

Now let $f_i$ denote the function ($Ord$ to $Ord$) whose restriction corresponds to the $\lambda_{i-1}$-recursive function (with cofinality $\lambda_{i-1}$) from $\lambda_i$ to $\lambda_{i-1}$. What is bothering me here is that for a large enough value $\beta \geq \omega_1 \cdot 2$ we would have $\beta$-recursive functions and $\beta$-computable functions as exactly the same. But that would seems to imply that corresponding to $f_i$ there is an OTM with index $e_i$ that computes this function $f_i$. More specifically, the index for $f_n$ will be $e_n$. Now because we **assumed** that $\lambda_n \in S$, shouldn't there be a very simple program for the model $Comp$ which halts with the designated variable value equal to $\lambda_{n-1}$ (hence violating $\lambda_{n-1} \notin S$)? For example: $\lambda_{n-1}=sup \{f_n(x)|x<\lambda_n\}$. A similar observation "seems" to hold for all other $\lambda_i$'s with $i \leq n-1$.

I think I might be going wrong with something really simple here (since it can't be that easy), but I can't seem to identify it clearly. Anyway, I hope this question is written more clearly than the one which I deleted.

Comment: I don't understand the connection between $Comp$ and $\alpha$-recursion: you want the former to have only countably many programs, but the latter doesn't (remember, $\Sigma_1$-definability *allows parameters*, so there are uncountably many $\alpha$-recursive functions whenever $\alpha$ is uncountable.

Comment: Also, what does the cofinality of a *function* mean? Finally, for any $\alpha\in [\omega_1,\theta)$ there is a $\theta$-recursive surjection from $\omega_1$ to $\alpha$, so you might as well just take $\lambda_1=\omega_1$, which - being admissible - terminates the chain.

Comment: As to "isn't "*total $\Sigma_1(L_{\alpha})$-definable function*" supposed to mean $\alpha$-recursive function?," that's the *definition* of "$\alpha$-recursive function." So there's no "supposed to mean" here, that's just what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Counting computations

*Below I'm restricting attention to "reasonably closed" ordinals for simplicity.*

I think you're conflating *programs* and *computable functions* (and this is something I find annoying about Koepke's presentation, FWIW). Briefly: **computable functions are programs with parameters**.

There are indeed only countably many ORM-programs. However, an $\alpha$-computable function is given, not just by a program, but by a program **with some tuple of parameters** (see Definitions $1$ and $2$). Specifically, an $\alpha$-computable function is given by a pair $(P,p)$ where $P$ is a program and $p$ is a finite tuple of ordinals $<\alpha$. As a consequence, for any given $\alpha$ there are $\vert\alpha\vert$-many $\alpha$-computable functions.

- Note that the same is true of the $\alpha$-recursive functions: an $\alpha$-recursive function is essentially just a $\Sigma_1$ formula with parameters from $L_\alpha$.

As far as I can tell, this resolves the issue.

> Incidentally, the following language may be a bit clearer. For each $n\in\omega$ we have a notion of "$n$-ary ORM program." There are only countably many of these. A **$k$-ary $\alpha$-computable function** is then a "projection of a program:" a partial function $f:\alpha\rightarrow\alpha$ is $\alpha$-computable iff there is some $(k+m)$-ary program $P$ and some $\rho_1,...,\rho_m<\alpha$ such that for all $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_k<\alpha$ we have $$f(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_k)\simeq P(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_k,\rho_1,...,\rho_m).$$

---

### Dropping parameters

Now let me address the "dependence graph" idea you've described in the comments below, clarifying the $\lambda$-stuff. The issue is that **the parameters may indeed have to drop below $\omega_1$**. They can then of course be admissible, ending the process and killing the argument.

There are two key issues here:

- The first is [**Fodor's lemma**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fodor%27s_lemma), a kind of sophisticated counting argument which says that we can never keep dropping down in the way we would have to in order to avoid this. Basically, Fodor tells us that if we could avoid dropping parameters, we'd have lots of different $\alpha\in(\omega_1,\omega_1+\omega_1)$ whose inadmissibility is witnessed by the same program and parameter tuple.
- Now we need to argue that that can't happen, and this is the second key issue, which is a consequence of the "uniformly $\Sigma_1$-ness" of recursion: halting and outputting a value is witnessed by a single existential fact, so we can't have the same computation converge in two different ways in different contexts.

As the above suggests, a much more general fact holds: any "reasonable" computability theory gives rise to a notion of admissibility for which this same "parameter-dropping" has to happen (see the **theorem** below). This is a bit technical, but it's very much worth understanding.

---

### Generalized computability theories

> **Definition**. A *good computation notion* is a partial class function $$F: Ord\times \omega\times Ord^{<\omega}\times Ord\rightarrow Ord$$ satisfying the following two properties:
>
> - **Domain/range are good**: $F(\alpha,e,{\bf p},\zeta)=\eta$ implies ${\bf p},\zeta,\eta<\alpha$ and $\alpha$ is closed under exponentation.
> - **Absoluteness of computations**: whenever $F(\alpha_0,e,{\bf p},\zeta)$ and $F(\alpha_1,e,{\bf p},\zeta)$ are each defined, they are equal.
>
> For simplicity, write "$F^\alpha_{e,{\bf p}}$" for the partial map $$\alpha\rightarrow\alpha: \zeta\mapsto F(\alpha,e,{\bf p},\zeta).$$ We read "$F_{e,{\bf p}}^\alpha(\zeta)=\eta$" as "in the context of $\alpha$, program $e$ with parameter tuple ${\bf p}$ on input $\zeta$ halts and equals $\eta$."

That's it! This is a *really* broad notion. In particular, it's easy to check that both recursion and computability in the senses above are good computation notions *(once we tweak things slightly to allow programs to take arbitrary finite tuples of ordinals as parameters)*, the key point being that absoluteness follows from uniform $\Sigma_1$-definability over the relevant levels of the $L$-hierarchy.

Every good computation notion has an associated notion of admissibility:

> If $F$ is a good computation notion, an ordinal $\alpha$ is $F$-admissible iff $\alpha$ is exponentially closed and there are no $e\in\omega$ and $\beta,{\bf p}<\alpha$ such that $\beta\subseteq dom(F_{e,{\bf p}}^\alpha)$ and $F_{e,{\bf p}}^\alpha[\beta]=\alpha$.
>
> On the other hand, if there *are* such $e,\beta,{\bf p}$, we say that $(F^\alpha_{e,{\bf p}},\beta)$ *witnesses the $F$-inadmissibility of $\alpha$*.

For example - fixing a good computation notion $F$ - every uncountable regular cardinal is trivially $F$-admissible, while every $\alpha\in(\omega_1,\omega_1+\omega_1)$ is $F$-inadmissible via the addition clause. Finally - and this will be used implicitly below - if $(F^\alpha_{e,{\bf p}},\beta)$ witnesses the $F$-inadmissibility of $\alpha$ then $\vert\beta\vert=\vert\alpha\vert$.

- NOTE: This admissibility notion appears to differ from the usual notion, since we've demanded totality restricted to $\beta$ instead of genuine totality and we've demanded onto-ness instead of cofinality. However, it's a good exercise to check that they coincide *(HINT: add $\beta$ as another parameter and use an "if-then-else" construction.)*

Finally, I'll need a version of Fodor's lemma:

> **Modified Fodor**: Let $S$ be a stationary set of countable ordinals. Suppose $G: S\rightarrow\omega_1{}^{<\omega}$ is regressive in the sense that $G(\sigma)\in\sigma^{<\omega}$. Then $G$ is constant on a stationary set.

Deducing this from the usual Fodor's lemma is a good exercise.

Here, then, is my claim:

> **Theorem**: Suppose $F$ is a good computation notion. Then there is a statioary set of countable ordinals $S$ such that for every $\alpha\in S$, whenever $(F^\alpha_{e,{\bf p}},\beta)$ witnesses the $F$-inadmissibility of $\omega_1+\alpha$ there is some element of ${\bf p}$ which is $<\omega_1$.

That is, "parameters sometimes have to drop."

*Proof.* Suppose otherwise. Let $S$ be the set of countable ordinals $\alpha$ such that $\omega_1+\alpha$ is exponentiatially closed. Let $G:S\rightarrow\omega_1{}^{<\omega}$ be any function sending each $\alpha\in S$ to some tuple $\langle e,\delta_1,...,\delta_n,\beta\rangle$ such that $$(F^{\omega_1+\alpha}_{e,\langle \omega_1+\delta_1,...,\omega_1+\delta_n\rangle},\omega_1+\beta)$$ witnesses the $F$-inadmissibility of $\omega_1+\alpha$.

The function $G$ is regressive in the sense of the Fodor theorem above, and $S$ is stationary (indeed, club). So there is some stationary $T\subseteq S$ such that $G$ is constant - with value $\langle e,\delta_1,...,\delta_n,\beta\rangle$ - on $T$. For brevity let $${\bf p}=\langle \omega_1+\delta_1,...,\omega_1+\delta_n\rangle.$$

Now pick ordinals $\alpha_0<\alpha_1$ in $T$. Note that $\delta_1,...,\delta_n,\beta$ must all be $<\alpha_0,\alpha_1$ by definition of $T$. Now since $$(F^{\alpha_1}_{e,{\bf p}},\beta)$$ witnesses the $F$-inadmissibility of $\alpha_1$, there must be some $\zeta<\omega_1+\beta$ such that $$F(\alpha_1,e,{\bf p},\zeta)=\alpha_0+1.$$ But since $$F^{\alpha_0}_{e,{\bf p}}$$ witnesses the $F$-inadmissibility of $\alpha_0$ we must have some $\eta<\alpha_0$ such that $$F(\alpha_0,e,{\bf p}, \zeta)=\eta.$$ By absoluteness of $F$ this implies $\alpha_0+1=\eta<\alpha_0$, a contradiction. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't read your answer (I just saw it) yet but I think I had some understanding of the issue about parameters now after reading your first comment. Specifically, to be clear, I am thinking that for $\alpha$-computable function (say fixed input variables) you not only have an index but an arbitrary number of finite parameters $<\alpha$ (say denoted by separately marked variables such as $p_i$). I was also assuming the parameters to be $0$ in the MO question (so this kind of resolves the main issue I had in that question too), since it wasn't clear to me at that time.

Comment: This clears things up quite a bit, but there is still something on my mind. For example, in your comment you said that we can take $\lambda_0=\alpha$, $\lambda_1=\omega_1$. But some things aren't fully clear to me. According to the definition I quoted, we would need to consider a $\lambda_1$-recursive function specifically. There is also something else I am thinking about. If we draw a dependency graph with "nodes" as "ordinals" and segments labelled with either $d$ (for domain), $p$ (for parameter) the issue I am thinking is that wouldn't this dependency graph have all its (continued)

Comment: elements in $S$ only in finite attempts. This doesn't seem to fit in very well (in my mind). What I mean by "dependency graph" is roughly that one starts with $\omega_1 \leq \alpha<\omega_1 \cdot 2$ as a base node and then expand from there. This isn't reflected in the question as it is right now. I will try to think about it and possibly modify it later and try to describe things more precisely (if I can make it precise).

Comment: @SSequence "According to the definition I quoted, we would need to consider a $\lambda_1$-recursive function specifically." No, reread the definition: $\alpha$ is admissible if there is no total $\alpha$-recursive function mapping some $\beta<\alpha$ cofinally into $\alpha$.

Comment: Elaborating on my previous comment: it doesn't make sense, when $\beta<\alpha$, to talk about a $\beta$-recursive function into $\alpha$: the domain of an $\eta$-recursive function is always (a subset of) $L_\eta$. Meanwhile I don't understand what your "dependency graph" is supposed to be.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was a typo. You are right. What I meant to write was: "According to the definition I quoted, we would need to consider a $\lambda_0$-recursive function specifically." What I meant roughly with "dependency graph" was that when we consider a $\lambda_0$-recursive function we would get a finite number of parameters all less than $\lambda_0$ (or no?) alongside with a value $\lambda_1$ (as mentioned in question). But if we think of this as one pass, we can keep repeating this process leading to a finite graph so that all "bottom" nodes are in $S$ (very roughly speaking).

Comment: The thing that is bothering me (for now at least) is that it seems to me that with bottom nodes in $S$ (which I described in question), it seems all the information is available (since it is finite) to set a $Comp$ program halting with a variable value equal to $\lambda_0$.

Comment: @SSequence Re: "According to the definition I quoted, we would need to consider a $\lambda_0$-recursive function specifically" Well, yes, that's what I did in my answer ("whenever $\alpha\in[\gamma,\delta)$ where $\gamma$ is admissible and $\delta$ is the next admissible above $\gamma$, there is an $\alpha$-recursive function mapping $\gamma$ onto $\alpha$" - remember $\lambda_0=\alpha$). So I'm not sure what the objection is there.

Comment: Yes, I think you are understanding (or more or less something close) with what I am trying to say with "dependency graph". Perhaps I probably need to edit the question later on (if needed), but maybe you have an answer in mind already.

Comment: @SSequence I've edited to explain what goes wrong with that.

Comment: Though I don't understand the second part of your answer, I think you are right. The way I have been thinking about it (very informally ofc) is that a certain measure of how powerful a given computational model is the "count" of the halting positions (say $c$). For $Comp$, this will ofc be countable as opposed to $sup$ of halting positions (which will be uncountable). For ordinary ORMs, both $c$ and $C$ are equal. Anyway, for the question, I think around the point $\omega_1+c$ or above I don't see any natural decomposition except: $dom=c$, $para$-$1=\omega_1$, $para$-$2=c$ (continued)

Comment: And importantly, there I can't see any strategy to reduce $para$-$2$ to a values less than $c$, so what you are saying seems to confirm that. Anyway, "dependency graphs" seem reasonably interesting. For one, based on these, I have gotten a good idea about (total) $\theta$-recursive injection from $\theta$ to $\omega_1$ that you were talking about. [when $\alpha$ is good admissible such an injection from $\alpha^+$ to $\alpha$ seemed reasonable to me, but I had no idea how such an injection would look like for bad admissible $\alpha$.]

Comment: *Regarding your comment:* my feeling is it might be a bit advanced for me. But perhaps I might be able to understand it if I read it patiently. I will probably try to take a more detailed look later on. At any rate, I have also gotten some idea about recovering the construction in my MO question after learning about the problematic assumption (that I made there). After thinking about it for few hours, I think I *might* be able to recover it (but ofc its difficult to be reasonably certain so soon since I posted the original question after weeks of examining it).

Comment: @SSequence I've edited my answer - the point I glossed over initially in the technical part was the *absoluteness* of the relevant computability theory. I've divided that part into two pieces now, a quick informal summary and a more technical general result.